# Bootstrap reset button onclick keep textbox as valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used below code for bootstrap textbox and textarea and also in the last div I have used button type="reset" .But when I entered invalid shop name and valid Address and click on Reset button it reset it and after only entering invalid shop name and click on Add shop then it is successfully adding new shop.Both the textbox show green background-color and correct sign even after it is empty. 
Please help me.
Please see below image after onclick of reset button:

[image]

```
                    <form id="defaultForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" 
                          data-bv-message="This value is not valid"
                          data-bv-feedbackicons-valid="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
                          data-bv-feedbackicons-invalid="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
                          data-bv-feedbackicons-validating="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Shop Name</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="^[a-zA-Z\s]+$"
                                data-bv-regexp-message="The shop name can consist of alphabetical characters only" name="shopName" placeholder="Shop Name" data-bv-trigger="blur" data-bv-notempty="true" data-bv-notempty-message="Shop name is required and cannot be empty" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Shop Address</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <textarea id="id_txt_addr" type="text" class="form-control" name="shop_address" placeholder="Shop Address" style="height:100px" maxlength="200" data-bv-trigger="blur" data-bv-notempty="true" data-bv-notempty-message="Shop address is required and cannot be empty"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
                                <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Add Shop">
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: can you send demo for your problem

Comment: https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/issues/68

Comment: @Sasikumar i cant send demo of this application but I have done with javascript validation.Thank you  for your quick response . Please vote up for me If question is helpful

Comment: @MoshFeu Thanks it is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On reset button click, remove all relevant validation classes and elements handling error message inside closest form. Here an example:

```
$(':reset').on('click', function(){
    var $form = $(this).closest("form");
    $form.find('*').removeClass('has-success has-error glyphicon-ok glyphicon-remove');
    $form.find('.help-block').remove();
});
```

### -DEMO-

Now maybe there is a bootstrap method to reset validation, you should check bootstrap DOC maybe.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ibtReset").on("click", function () {
            $('#ShopName').val("");
            $('#id_txt_addr').val("");
            $('.glyphicon ').remove();
        });
    });
```

On reset button click both the values become empty.
It may help You.